# uncheck when clicked outside javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have built a dropdown- menu with CSS and plain JavaScript. When someone has checked the input element, the dropdown-menu will toggle down which is exactly what I want. Only the struggle I have met now is the JavaScript part. The checkbox should ONLY be unchecked when someone has not clicked on the dropdown-menu itself and the label (because the input/label works well with pure CSS). Anything outside that would trigger this function. Only in plain JavaScript!

```js
function validate(e){
 var e = event || window.event, // make this works in different browsers 
  checkNavbar = document.getElementById("navbar-dropdown-toggle"),  // input
  checkboxNavbar = document.getElementById("checkboxNavbar"), // label
  storeDropdown = document.getElementById("storeDropdown"); // unordered list dropdown-menu

  
 if (checkNavbar.checked == true && e.target != checkboxNavbar) { //check if checbox is already checked
  console.log("checkbox is checked");
  if(e.target != storeDropdown) {
   console.log("you do not click on ul and label");
   if(checkNavbar.checked == false) { // if it is clicked outside
   checkNavbar.checked = false; // if that is true we should uncheck the checkbox 
   return false;
   }
  } 
 } 
};

document.addEventListener("click", validate);
```

```css
.dropdown-label-navbar {
 height: 55px;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
.navbar-dropdown {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -999px;
}
 .dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .navbar-dropdown:checked ~ .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  transition: max-height 1s;
  max-height: 300px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  border-top: 1px solid #828282;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #828282;
 }
 .dropdown-label-navbar {
  height: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<input id="navbar-dropdown-toggle" type="checkbox" class="navbar-dropdown"/>
                    <label class="dropdown-label-navbar" id="checkboxNavbar" for="navbar-dropdown-toggle"></label>

                    <a href="#99" class="main-links">Store</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="storeDropdown">
                        <div class="entire-block">
                            <div class="dropdown-image-block">

                            </div>
                             <li class="list-of-dropdown">
                                <div class="dropdown-list"><a href="case-and-protection.html">Cases and Protection</a></div>
                                <div class="dropdown-list"><a href="power_and_cable.html">Power and Cables</a></div>
                                <div class="dropdown-list"><a href="audio.html">Audio</a></div>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- There is no check for `checkNavbar`
- `checkNavbar.checked == false` will never satisfy, because you had already required that `checkNavbar.checked == true`
- `event` is not defined in `e = event || window.event`. It should be `e`.

If you want to avoid that clicking on the drop down executes the code to close it, then it is easiest to trap the click event on that element and stop the propagation of it. That way it never arrives at your document-level click handler.

Here is the corrected code:

```js
function validate(e){
    var e = e || window.event, // make this works in different browsers 
        checkNavbar = document.getElementById("navbar-dropdown-toggle"),
        checkboxNavbar = document.getElementById("checkboxNavbar");
        
    if ([checkNavbar, checkboxNavbar].indexOf(e.target) < 0 && checkNavbar.checked) {
        checkNavbar.checked = false;
        return false;
    }
};

document.addEventListener("click", validate);

var storeDropdown = document.getElementById("storeDropdown");
storeDropdown.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.dropdown-label-navbar {
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.navbar-dropdown {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -999px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar-dropdown:checked ~ .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    transition: max-height 1s;
    max-height: 300px;
    opacity: 1.0;
    border-top: 1px solid #828282;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #828282;
}
.dropdown-label-navbar {
    height: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input id="navbar-dropdown-toggle" type="checkbox" class="navbar-dropdown"/>
<label class="dropdown-label-navbar" id="checkboxNavbar" for="navbar-dropdown-toggle"></label>

<a href="#99" class="main-links">Store</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="storeDropdown">
    <div class="entire-block">
        <div class="dropdown-image-block">

        </div>
         <li class="list-of-dropdown">
            <div class="dropdown-list"><a href="case-and-protection.html">Cases and Protection</a></div>
            <div class="dropdown-list"><a href="power_and_cable.html">Power and Cables</a></div>
            <div class="dropdown-list"><a href="audio.html">Audio</a></div>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Or you could use the stop-bubbling method for all three elements:

```js
var checkNavbar = document.getElementById("navbar-dropdown-toggle"),
 checkboxNavbar = document.getElementById("checkboxNavbar"),
 storeDropdown = document.getElementById("storeDropdown");

function closeDropDown(){
    checkNavbar.checked = false;
}

function stopBubblingWhenChecked(e) {
    if (checkNavbar.checked) e.stopPropagation();
}

[checkNavbar, checkboxNavbar, storeDropdown].forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("click", stopBubblingWhenChecked);
});

document.addEventListener("click", closeDropDown);
```

```css
.dropdown-label-navbar {
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.navbar-dropdown {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -999px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar-dropdown:checked ~ .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    transition: max-height 1s;
    max-height: 300px;
    opacity: 1.0;
    border-top: 1px solid #828282;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #828282;
}
.dropdown-label-navbar {
    height: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input id="navbar-dropdown-toggle" type="checkbox" class="navbar-dropdown"/>
<label class="dropdown-label-navbar" id="checkboxNavbar" for="navbar-dropdown-toggle"></label>

<a href="#99" class="main-links">Store</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="storeDropdown">
    <div class="entire-block">
        <div class="dropdown-image-block">

        </div>
         <li class="list-of-dropdown">
            <div class="dropdown-list"><a href="case-and-protection.html">Cases and Protection</a></div>
            <div class="dropdown-list"><a href="power_and_cable.html">Power and Cables</a></div>
            <div class="dropdown-list"><a href="audio.html">Audio</a></div>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```